# What is wrong with this VB.NET extension method on SecureString?

Tags: .net, vb.net, extension-methods

When I try and compile, the following method results in the error, "BC30491 Expression does not produce a value":

```
<Extension()>
Public Sub FromClearString(ByRef secureString As SecureString, clearString As String)

    clearString.ToList().ForEach(Function(c) secureString.AppendChar(c))
    secureString.MakeReadOnly()

End Sub
```

It seems like a perfectly normal extension to me, but I don't work with VB very often. What could be wrong with it?

Comment: I would guess it is because `AppendChar()` is void and you return nothing from `Function(c)`.

Comment: use `Sub(c)` instead of `Function(c)`

Comment: You are also falling victim to a longstanding misunderstanding about `ByRef`. `ByRef` is the same as C#'s `ref`. In this case, you don't need it and shouldn't have it even if you can. In C#, that wouldn't compile because C# will not apply ExtensionAttribute to a method that but can't be called an extension method. Apparently, VB is more liberal. The extension method syntax is intended to have any expression on the left-hand side, not limited to a variable or field.

Comment: @TomBlodget I only added `ByRef` after trying a great many things, just in the vain hope that only for extension methods it may make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
clearString.ToList().ForEach('---> Function(c) '<--- secureString.AppendChar(c))
```

`ForEach` signature is `Action(Of T)`, and `.AppendChar(c)` doesn't return a thing

Correct way:

```
clearString.ToList().ForEach(Sub(c) secureString.AppendChar(c))
```

Comment: I do know how I missed that. I've done all my other, plenty, `Sub` lambdas correctly, but I've been trying to translate a day's worth of C# into VB.NET in few, tired, hours before bed. Thanks.

Comment: @ProfK there are plenty of tools to convert C# to VB https://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+to+VB

Comment: @ProfK It happens to best of us

Answer (score 0):

The SecureString.AppendChar() Method does not produce any value.

Try using this code

```
For Each chr as char in clearString
SecureString.AppedChar(chr)
Next
```

Comment: What's wrong with LINQ? And, BTW, a string is an implicit, but immutable, char array already, so `ToCharArray()` is unnecessary.